# OpenSSL decrypt AES 256bit (base64) encrypted password - wrong final block length

Tags: bash, encryption, openssl, aes

I am trying to decrypt aes-256-cdc encoded password using OpenSSL

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ak=BgL0cPoZQ4wZWOWl5mXBhlMsNbbZL2zvsWZXjuGy4Iw=
iv=cGEvcGWzE8t7CS3wbeoUFQ==
pass=RCQm23YHOCg3nxOl7CcQ7w==

#change format from base64 into hex
AES_KEY=$(echo "${ak}" | openssl base64 -d | xxd -p |tr -d '\n')
AES_IV=$(echo "${iv}" | openssl base64 -d | xxd -p)
ENCODED_PASSWORD=$(echo "${pass}" | openssl base64 -d | xxd -p)

echo "AES_KEY ${AES_KEY}"
echo "AES_IV ${AES_IV}"
echo "ENCODED_PASSWORD ${ENCODED_PASSWORD}"

#set password file
echo "${ENCODED_PASSWORD}" > in.txt

#decode password
openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -d -iv ${AES_IV} -K ${AES_KEY} -in in.txt
```

this results in error message

```
AES_KEY 0602f470fa19438c1958e5a5e665c186532c35b6d92f6cefb166578ee1b2e08c
AES_IV 70612f7065b313cb7b092df06dea1415
ENCODED_PASSWORD 53b7adff6e85baedfa9dab80109ad67d
▒▒▒▒▒▒`$;▒▒▒▒%▒O▒Q▒▒▒S▒▒<7 7
                            bad decrypt
32624:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:518:
0602f470fa19438c1958e5a5e665c186532c35b6d92f6cefb166578ee1b2
e08c
```

I think that the problem is aes-key (ak) which has a newline char in it, which I am trying to remove with

```
|tr -d '\n'
```

a password should decode as

```
password
```

Comment: `$(echo $ak | openssl base64 -d | xxd -p -c32)` will give the hex with no troublesome newline. Also `openssl enc` can decode base64 while decrypting, and `-nosalt` is ignored for non-PBE, so just `echo $pass | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -a -K $key -iv $iv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, what's wrong is the encoding of `in.txt`. It should not be text at all, it should be *binary*.

In principle you would not get this error either if you'd use `echo -n` suppressing the final end-of-line within the ciphertext. The decryption would however still fail as it expects binary instead of an *encoded* binary value.

You may want to change the name of `in.txt` to `in.bin` if you want to keep a file. You should also be able to simply pipe the ciphertext into `openssl` using the standard input (`stdin`). In that case you may want to encode it first to store it in a shell variable and then *decode* before piping it to `openssl` to decrypt it.

For binary, use `cat` instead of `echo`.

Comment: No, **don't keep binary data in a shell variable**; if it happens to contain null _most_ shells will truncate it outright, and even if the shell doesn't, trying to pass it to a program always will. Some shells may garble other 'unusual' bytes as well. Also not all versions of `echo` support `-n`, and in some versions a value happening to contain 0x5c will be corrupted. Binary in a _file_ is safe on nearly all systems today, otherwise better use hex _and decode it_ e.g. `xxd -r -p`, or use `enc -a/--base64` to base64 encode when encrypting and decode when decrypting.

Comment: Thanks Dave, adjusted answer - as usual :)

Answer (score 2):

If your $pass is long (more than 32 chars maybe), be sure to use openssl -A option, the reason is documented in the openssl manual.
With -A option, for encryption, the base64 encoded string will not be splitted in segments; For decryption, whole line is read to be decoded using base64.

Code example:

```
plaintxt='hello world"
pass=$(echo ${plaintxt} | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc  -a -K ${AES_KEY} -iv ${AES_IV} -A )    
echo "decoded password is: "
echo ${pass} | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -d -a -K ${AES_KEY} -iv ${AES_IV} -A
```

Answer (score 1):

this works as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#base64 encoded aes key, iv and password
ak=BgL0cPoZQ4wZWOWl5mXBhlMsNbbZL2zvsWZXjuGy4Iw=
iv=cGEvcGWzE8t7CS3wbeoUFQ==
pass=OfOXO+ruKFTCsBwGHynXwA==

#change format from base64 into hex, for openssl to consume, xxd -p -c32 is taking care of wrapping of the new lines
AES_KEY=$(echo ${ak} | openssl base64 -d | xxd -p -c32)
AES_IV=$(echo ${iv} | openssl base64 -d | xxd -p -c32)

echo "AES_KEY ${ak}"
echo "AES_IV ${iv}"
echo "encoded password ${pass}"
echo "decoded password is: "
echo ${pass} | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -a -K ${AES_KEY} -iv ${AES_IV}
```

explanation:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d
```

decode using aes-256-cbc algo

```
-a
```

in our case, it means that openssl will accept base64 encoded password

```
-K
```

aes key

```
-iv
```

aes iv